Is there a differential form which corresponds to an eigenvalue of the homomorphism in cohomology?
Let $M$ be a closed manifold and $f:M\to M$ be a diffeomorphism. Suppose the homomorphism $f^*:H^k(M;\mathbb R)\to H^k(M;\mathbb R)$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. Note that $\lambda$ is algebraic but possibly not integer.
Does there always exist closed and not exact differential form $\alpha\in\Omega^k(M)$ such that $f_1^*(\alpha)=\lambda\alpha$ for some diffeomorphism $f_1$ homotopic to $f$?

I guess if you can find a Riemannian metric invariant under $f$ then you can use a harmonic form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology#Harmonic_forms

Let's consider the case $M$ is a surface, $f$ is pseudo-Anosov, and $k=1$. A 1-form $\alpha \in \Omega^1(M)$ induces a singular foliation on $M$, and the statement that $f^*\alpha = \lambda \alpha$ means that that singular foliation is invariant under $f$. I somehow feel that the requirement that $\alpha$ be smooth will lead to a contradiction...

@AndréHenriques the zeroes of $\alpha$ correspond to the singularities of this foliation. However, if foliation is given by a 1-form (not by quadratic differential), all its singularities have even number of prongs (not like in pseudo-Anosov theory). Finally, if the set of zeroes of $\alpha$ has nonempty interior, then $\alpha$ does not define a foliation on the whole of $M$

@QiaochuYuan Unfortunately, a metric with nontrivial automorphism is an exceptional situation, so for arbitrary $M$ and $f$ such a metric does not exist

I assume $\lambda$ is a real eigenvalue?

@GregFriedman yes, $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$

Do you want to assume $\alpha$ is closed and not exact? You at least need to assume $\alpha\neq 0$ as otherwise the statement is trivial.

@WillSawin sure i do

$f$ pseudo-Anosov will generally have more real eigenvalues on $H^1$ then just the stretch factor (indeed, the stretch factor need not be an eigenvalue at all). However, it fixes only two points on the Thurston boundary. So if we show that any eigenform $\alpha$ must correspond to a point on the Thurston boundary and the two fixed points can only correspond to eigenforms with the obvious eigenvalues then we're done. We don't need to prove anything about singularities.

However, as you point out, $\alpha$ need not itself define a foliation. However, we can perturb $\alpha$ by a generic $1$-form to produce a foliation and thus a point in the Thurston boundary. If we send the perturbations to zero, do these points converge? A positive answer should give a negative answer to your question. But I'm not familiar enough with the Thurston boundary / simple closed curves to answer.
